# Using Cooking Hacks GPS/GSM shield with Android

Tags: android, gps, gsm

I am new to RPi and was hoping that users had experience using the GPS/GSM shield with any Android OS.  If there is some success with this device working with Android, I was going to give it a shot.  I am not a programmer so 'making it work' would not happen unless I could follow detailed instructions or a YouTube video which does not appear to exist.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think GSM modules are usually just serial devices (controlled using [AT modem commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set), so presuming Android IoT exposes that, if you *were* a programmer it would not be hard; the hardest part might be connecting audio).  Since you're not, your only option here is if someone's written an app...